# Apps Script Triggers Don't Work For Shared Document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

I have a document shared with a friend. I added an Apps-Script code to that specific document. Then, I added a trigger to the code to execute whenever the document is opened (onOpen). However, it doesn't work on either accounts.

I tried creating a trigger using the "Current project's triggers" tab, but that didn't work. I even tried creating a trigger in the code, but nothing happened. It is an onOpen trigger.

```
var build = ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .forDocument(DocumentApp.getActiveDocument())
    .onOpen()
    .create();
```

The code should run when the document is opened on both accounts. However, it doesn't even run the code at all. I tried looking up a solution, but I found nothing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Create a [mcve] of the myFunction code and add it to the question.

Comment: Probably the required scopes have changed and reauthorization is required. Note that a new trigger is created *every* time that `create()` is called, so if that is run more than once you will create a nightmare for yourself. If you know the document at the time of writing the code, just create the trigger manually (and avoid needing the extra OAuth scopes).